# Probable meaning of "どかのじょ"in the title?

Tags: meaning

*newest:In fact ,just a wrong spliting.By it,there is any else letter easy to split wrongly for beginner or how to avoid it(I think はーどもーmeans hi~hello because sounds like it@-@)*

Original texts:Ok,I find meaning in the machine(just like Google Translate) making:"local girl","she","wheresome"——this is most confusing one.But there is actually a title:"はーどもーどかのじょ"[<$>its link<$>](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GU4sm9lrZPw)of a song.According to original music,what is the probable or appropriate meaning in the original title?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> はーどもーどかのじょ

Hard-mode girlfriend

Comment: I splited it incorrectly,I have knowed it lol